# How do I declare circular dependant abstract Classes in F#

Tags: .net, f#, abstract-class, circular-dependency, circular-reference

Consider the two abstract classes alpha and beta:

```
[<AbstractClass>]  
type alpha () =
    abstract member foo: beta->beta

[<AbstractClass>] 
and beta () = //***
    abstract member bar: alpha
```

If I try to compile that I get an error,
on the line indicated with * * *:

```
error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'and' in interaction
```

And if I write:

```
[<AbstractClass>]  
type alpha () =
    abstract member foo: beta->beta

and beta () =
    abstract member bar: alpha
```

then I get:

```
error FS0365: No implementation was given for 'abstract member beta.bar : alpha'
```

and the hint that I should add  the AbstractClass Attribute

So how do i declare circularly defined abstract classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the attribute after the 'and' keyword:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type alpha () =
    abstract member foo : beta -> beta

and [<AbstractClass>]  beta () =
    abstract member bar : alpha
```